# ElasticSearch match query issue

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I have a string field I"m doing a match query against:

```
{
  query : {
    match: {
       "grounds": "one"
    } 
  }
}
```

When I execute this query, it works but, if I put

```
{
      query : {
        match: {
           "grounds": "one vote"
        } 
      }
    }
```

It doesn't return any values. Bear in mind that what's indexed for `grounds` is *one*. My understanding of how ElasticSearch works is that it tokenize each of the words during query time and match against the inverse index. If i'm wrong, kindly advise.

**UPDATED**

My mapping definition for ground is:

```
"grounds": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
              },
```

How I define my custom `synonym_analyzer` is this:

```
 client.CreateIndex(index, c => c
               .Settings(s => s.Analysis(
                   a => a.Analyzers(an => an
                                .Custom("synonym_analyzer", ca => ca
                                    .Tokenizer("standard")
                                    .Filters("synonym","lowercase")
                                )
                            ).TokenFilters(t => t.Synonym("synonym", ss => synonyms))
```

Thanks.

Comment: If all is at default, you are right, see default operator here:     https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html . How is grounds defined.

Comment: @Harald thanks for the reply. I updated my post regarding the mapping for `grounds` to give you more context. Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with the programmatic approach of creating the index, but it looks like you basically use the StandardTokenizer and a SynonymFilter. You may want to try https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_testing_analyzers.html to see what your analyser actually spits out.

Comment: Here are the "testing analyzers" docs for NEST: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/testing-analyzers.html

Comment: @RussCam  I got the issue fixed. It seems to be working without any fix (probably my test cases were wrong). Thanks for the help.